# NextJS Input box loosing the focus after every character typed

Tags: next.js, input

I gone thru all the post and found a workaround hack using the ref to bring back the focus. But this code was working fine and suddenly all the pages have loosing focus issue. And i am loosing my head over it. With my previous version code, I went thru line by line but could not find any change. So, I just want from all the NextJS guru's here, why does i suddenly started losing focus on my app. Thanks in advance, you will save me hours of work, else i have to keep using the reference hack everywhere. next: 13.0.0, react: 18.2.0, nextui-org/react: ^2.1.13, typescript:4.3.4.

Here is the code example

````
  return (
    <Layout>
          <div className="flex w-full flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap  mb-2">
            <Input
              id="txtCompanyName"
              key="txtCompanyName"
              label="Company Name"
              isRequired
              type="string"
              value={company_name}
              onChange={handle_company_name_InputChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex w-full flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap  mb-2">
            <Input
              id="txtDivision"
              key={"txtDivision"}
              label="Division Name"
              type="string"
              value={division}
              onChange={handle_division_InputChange}
            />
          </div>
         </div>
        </Layout>
       )

    ```
````

Comment: Can't replicate,  https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/input-lose-focus-stack-4fwqyz Could you provide your input component code? As far as I can see type=string might be incorrect. Also might be worth using react-hook-form library to avoid such issues.